# Why are CUDA indices 2D?

Tags: cuda, opencl, nvidia

In CUDA (and OpenCL), indices of threads/blocks can be 1D, 2D or 3D.

Is this just for convenience to the programmer, or can there actually be a performance benefit when those are used, instead of mapping an integer index to 2 values using mod and div, for example?